# [C#]Verbatim string literal in File path?

Tags: c#, string, stream, webclient, literals

I need help on this.Normally if i use OpenFileDialog , i will generally be given back something like this on the FileName property:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Users\\SkyDrive\\Study Stuffs\\C and C++ development\\Comp Sci 322 - C Sharp\\Projects\\Main_UI_Older\\Test Case\\a test.xml";
```

This will work directly if i use it to create a new FileStream off it. I.E:

```
FileStream my_fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); // Works just fine.
```

But this will refuse to work with WebClient.DownloadFile method.

```
        WebClient my_downloader = new WebClient();
        my_downloader.DownloadFile("[URL HERE]", path);  //Will not work. WebException
        my_downloader.DownloadFile("[URL HERE]", @path); //Works.
```

I am forced to use the "@" in front of path inorder to get it working. Little bit of searching online left me scratching my head with "Verbatim String Literal". I googled around a bit, but it still left me scratching my head. I did this example:

```
    string test_1 = "C:\\Test";
    Console.WriteLine(@test_1);      //Print C:\Test
    Console.WriteLine(test_1);       //Print C:\Test
```

Can somebody explain this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception your webclient gives?

Comment: Your examples don't make sense. The `@` character is used in two completely different ways in C#. If it precedes a _string literal_ (i.e. some text written in between a pair of double-quotation marks), then it specifies a "verbatim string", as you found. This turns off backslash escaping, and is useful for specifying file paths. If it precedes an identifier, as in your `@path` and `@test_1` examples, it's just a way of allowing you to use reserved words in your program. E.g. you could name a variable `@for`, even though `for` would not be allowed.

Comment: It just said WebException was unhandled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, string fileName)` actually just calls the following internally

```
fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

Which by all reasoning is the same as your example of

```
FileStream my_fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

It seems the exception is not associated with the fileName at all, and must be something else

Comment: I will try a re-install of Visual Studio to see if that's help. Because it just doesn't make more sense why the compiler is giving me trouble after Peter Duniho's post about the use of "@" infront of a variable.

Comment: Re-installation wont help, try a clean and rebuild, sometimes it can help

Comment: Heh, a quick Repair and a new solution (copy and paste code). It just works now... Thanks for your time and help, dumb me.